# Username with folder mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this problem, I have this url example.com/directory/fotos/index.php?u=username and what I need to do is change it to
example.com/username/fotos
I already have a rule in htacces which changes the directory to username in case a username is found in index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ directory/index.php?u=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Which ouputs example.com/someusername

How can I do a new rule for the above case without conflicting with the current rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([^/]+)/fotos/?
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /directory/index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory/fotos/?
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/fotos/?$ /directory/fotos/index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```